# ‰ Shown up as <U+3020> in axis title (ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, unicode, title

I am making a boxplot about the isotope values of bone samples, and I want to set the y-axis title as "δ13C(‰)". However, ‰ always showed up as <U+2030> and I got "δ13C(<U+2030>)" as the axis title.

The code I used:

```
    #d13C / bone source
ggplot(Box1, aes(Box1$`Source of Fish bones`, Box1$d13C,fill=Box1$`Location of Pellets`)) +
geom_boxplot()+ theme_bw()+labs(title="δ13C / Fish Bone Source",x ="Source of Bones",
 y = "d13C",fill="Location of Pellets")+ 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
xlab("Source of Fish Bones")+
ylab(expression(delta*"13C ("*"\u2030"*")"))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this work for you? (simplified example) `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + labs(y = "δ13C(‰)")`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much